# Instance variable nil after it has been set

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a class with an object `incall`. I have a method that sets it and another methods that runs a method available for that object.

Here is my header file:

```
@interface RCTPlivo : NSObject <PlivoEndpointDelegate, CXProviderDelegate>

@property (nonatomic) PlivoIncoming *incall;

@property (nonatomic) PlivoEndpoint *endpoint;

@end
```

And here is my implementation file:

```
@implementation RCTPlivo

- (void)login {
    endpoint = [[PlivoEndpoint alloc] init];
    [endpoint login:plivoUser AndPassword:plivoPass];
    endpoint.delegate = self;
}

- (void)triggerIncomingCall {

    ...

    CXProvider *callkitProvider = [[CXProvider alloc] initWithConfiguration: configuration];
    [callkitProvider setDelegate:self queue:nil];

    ...

    [callkitProvider reportNewIncomingCallWithUUID:currentCall  update:update completion:^(NSError * _Nullable error) {
        if (error) {
            NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }
    }];
}

- (void)onIncomingCall:(PlivoIncoming *)incoming {
    // setting 
    self.incall = incoming
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action
{
    // Here self.incall is null
    [self.incall answer];
}

@end
```

When i log `self.incall` in perfromAnswerCall delegate it's null. When I log it in the onIncomingCall delegate the variable is set.

What am I missing here?

**Update**
Added the code that initializes the delegates and removed ivars.

Comment: You are setting it on a wrong instance.

Comment: So how would I do it the correct way? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: You need to show how you are doing it the incorrect way first. I mean, the context in which you call the setter, an the context in which the delegate is being called.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight added additional code to show the context. Basically I trigger the triggerIncomingCall method after running login.

Comment: Don't create ivars or synthesise them. This has been done automatically for the past 4 years. Just use the property.

Comment: Tried that as well. Still the same issue @Fogmeister

Comment: Just for curiosity. What happens if you log _incall and incall (one with and one without an underscore)?

Comment: Additionally. Either set a watch breakpoint on the value of incall or set a kvo method for will change value for key. On incall. See if it's being changed somewhere.

Comment: Good points. Let me do that and share the result.

Comment: @Fogmeister loggin _incall still gives me null. Setting KVO now.

Comment: @Ismailp the fact that it allows you to log it shows that you are confusing yourself with your ivars. Delete the ivars first just so that you know you're dealing with the right thing. In your case `self.incall == _incall` and `incall` is unrelated to either. So your ivar is actually not being used at all.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/124418/discussion-between-ismailp-and-fogmeister).

Comment: @dasblinkenlight you were right about the context. I accidentally had two instances of the RCTPlivo class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way this can happen is that you somehow have two separate instances of RCTPlivo. Try stopping the debugger in each of those calls and in the debugger do:

`(lldb) po self`

If everything's ok then the addresses should be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Your interface should be:

```
@interface RCTPlivo : NSObject <PlivoEndpointDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) PlivoIncoming *incall;

@end
```

and your implementation should be:

```
@implementation RCTPlivo

- (void)onIncomingCall:(PlivoIncoming *)incoming {
    self.incall = incoming;
}

- (void)provider:(CXProvider *)provider performAnswerCallAction:(CXAnswerCallAction *)action {
    [self.incall answer];
}

@end
```

Comment: So a) something else is setting self.incall to nil between the two calls or b) `incoming` is nil to start with (which you said it isn't). I don't see any other options. Under ARC it's not possible for a strong pointer to set itself to nil.

Comment: nothing else is setting it to nil and incoming is not nil either. I'm beginning to think that the delegate method hasn't got access to the instance variable. Could that be the case?

Comment: The only other way I can think this can happen is that you somehow have two separate instances of RCTPlivo. Try stopping the debugger in each of those calls and `po self` - if everything's ok then the addresses should be the same.

Comment: Ok will try that.

Comment: Well you were right, turns out I unintentionally hade two instances of the same class. Issue fixed itself after getting rid of one. Please add an answer so I can accept it. @norders

Comment: Great - I've added this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `infall` property is not defined as `strong`. So we can assume that there is no `strong` reference to the original object outside this method and it was released.

**Update**

This property was mentioned as *delegate* so its `weak` nature can be a designated behaviour and if this is an option the message sender should have a `strong` property holding the object reference.

Comment: so would @property (nonatomic, strong) PlivoIncoming *incall; be a proper solution?

Comment: I am reasonably certain that "strong" is the default.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight actually `assign //default`